# XSLT sort by attribute value

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a question about how to sort based on attribute value.

I have the following source document and I would like to sort the track items by the value of the title class value.

Hopefully someone can help with this.

`input.xml`:

```xml
<trackList>

    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="STD">Data Two</title>
    </track>
    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="SH">Data Three</title>

    </track>
    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="STD">Data Four</title>

    </track>
    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="SH">Data Five</title>

    </track>
</trackList>
```

The final output should look like this:

`output.xml`:

```
<trackList>
        
    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="SH">Data Three</title>
            
    </track>
        
    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="SH">Data Five</title>
            
    </track>
        
    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="STD">Data Four</title>
            
    </track>
    <track>
        <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
        <title class="STD">Data Two</title>
    </track>
</trackList>
```

I have tried the following but it does not work.

`my-stylesheet.xsl`:

```xml
<xsl:for-each-group select="title" group-by="@class">
                        
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:value-of select="@class"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
                        
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first `location` and `title` in your sample input don't have a `<track>` around them. Is that a copy/paste mistake or a characteristic of your input XML?

Comment: It is definitely a copy/paste mistake. They should be wrapped in <track></track>. I Just corrected.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="trackList">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="track">
        <xsl:sort select="title/@class"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<trackList>
  <track>
    <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
    <title class="SH">Data Three</title>

  </track>
  <track>
    <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
    <title class="SH">Data Five</title>

  </track>
  <track>
    <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
    <title class="STD">Data Two</title>
  </track>
  <track>
    <location>http://localhost/vmydoc</location>
    <title class="STD">Data Four</title>

  </track>
</trackList>
```

Comment: What if they are in a single smartform where you cannot have multiple field values, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372683/how-to-sort-entries-of-xml-using-xslt?noredirect=1#comment54539949_33372683