# XSLT: Sort based on child node's attribute doesn't work

Tags: xml, xslt

I just can't get sort function to work.

Basically I'm trying to do same as [XSLT sort by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713493/xslt-sort-by-attribute-value), but its just doesn't work

Input is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<result>
  <doc>
    <str name="hash1">EBFF15C2FB15BDD9C069EDF272EF43E738B276AA</str>
    <str name="org_data">
<items>
<orgdata amount ="5433" />
</items>
</str>
</doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="hash1">8CB2237D0679CA88DB6464EAC60DA96345513964</str>
    <str name="org_data">
<items>
<orgdata amount_rur="300"/>
<orgdata amount_rur="100"/>
<orgdata amount_rur="200"/>
<orgdata amount_rur="200" />
</items>
</str>
 </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

And I'm trying something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="rta-hashParticipantData1" select = "'8CB2237D0679CA88DB6464EAC60DA96345513964'"  />
    <xsl:param name="rta-hashParticipantData2"  select = "'EBFF15C2FB15BDD9C069EDF272EF43E738B276AA'" />
    <xsl:param name="rta-hashParticipantData3" />
    <xsl:param name="rta-role" select = "'123'"  />

    <xsl:template match="result">
        <xsl:copy>
            <roleName Role="{$rta-role}">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="doc" group-by="str[@name='hash1']">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()/str[@name='hash1']=$rta-hashParticipantData1">
                            <hashData hashName= '1' hashValue="{current-group()/str[@name='hash1']}" >
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/str[@name='org_data']" />
                            </hashData>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()/str[@name='hash1']=$rta-hashParticipantData2">
                            <hashData hashName= '2' hashValue="{current-group()/str[@name='hash1']}" >
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/str[@name='org_data']" />
                            </hashData>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()/str[@name='hash1']=$rta-hashParticipantData3">
                            <hashData hashName= '3' hashValue="{current-group()/str[@name='hash1']}" >
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/str[@name='org_data']" />
                            </hashData>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
            </roleName>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="photoUrls|str">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="roleName">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="hashData">
        <xsl:sort select="@hashName"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, I'm:

1) Grouping data by hash1 value

2) Adding some information (role, and hash number) based on global params. More specifically, I'm adding hashData element with hashName (hash number) and hashValue (hash value for debug) attributes.

3) Cleaning 'str' stuff

4) Trying to sort data within one role by hashData/@hashName

Last one doesn't work (it works if I'm doing it with another XSL tho). 
So, the question is - how to do it all in same XSL, and why it not working my way?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to sort the result you want to create so try to wrap your grouping creating the `hashData` elements into `xsl:perform-sort`:

```
<xsl:perform-sort>
  <xsl:sort select="@hashName"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="doc" group-by="str[@name='hash1']">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()/str[@name='hash1']=$rta-hashParticipantData1">
                            <hashData hashName= '1' hashValue="{current-group()/str[@name='hash1']}" >
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/str[@name='org_data']" />
                            </hashData>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()/str[@name='hash1']=$rta-hashParticipantData2">
                            <hashData hashName= '2' hashValue="{current-group()/str[@name='hash1']}" >
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/str[@name='org_data']" />
                            </hashData>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()/str[@name='hash1']=$rta-hashParticipantData3">
                            <hashData hashName= '3' hashValue="{current-group()/str[@name='hash1']}" >
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/str[@name='org_data']" />
                            </hashData>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:perform-sort>
```

Or group into a variable and then push the contents of the variable through apply-templates. Your template with `match="roleName"` can only be applied if you have created elements of that name in an input tree or a temporary tree.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to define a single parameter, consisting of a comma-delimited list of hashes, and then make use of `tokenize` and `index-of` to work out the hashName.

This would have the advantage of removing the `xsl:choose`, and allowing more than 3 parameters too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="rta-role" select = "'123'"  />

    <xsl:param name="rta-hashParticipantData" select="'8CB2237D0679CA88DB6464EAC60DA96345513964,EBFF15C2FB15BDD9C069EDF272EF43E738B276AA'" />

    <xsl:template match="result">
        <xsl:variable name="rta-hashParticipantDataList" select="tokenize($rta-hashParticipantData, ',')" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <roleName Role="{$rta-role}">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="doc" group-by="str[@name='hash1']">
                    <xsl:sort select="index-of($rta-hashParticipantDataList, current-grouping-key())" />
                    <hashData hashName="{index-of($rta-hashParticipantDataList, current-grouping-key())}" hashValue="{current-group()/str[@name='hash1']}" >
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/str[@name='org_data']" />
                    </hashData>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </roleName>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="photoUrls|str">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked out perfectly!